# Appositive phrase, but in conversational

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrase-requests

What else might you call, or how else might you name an appositive phrase, when used by a speaker interrupting for clarification

Betsy Smith:

> My sister,

Interruptor:

> Alice Smith

Betsy Smith:

> likes jelly beans.

An aside, a confirmatory aside, an appositive aside?

Comment: I'll certainly defer to someone with greater knowledge of pragmatics, but the interruption might be considered an example of a "back-channel" or even "conversational grounding". I'd be surprised if there were a specific term for appositives used in this manner.

Comment: It's one of many ways to instantiate turn-taking, which is Ground Zero for conversation. Note that they're taking turns; the grammar and especially its terminology is irrelevant, since it's based on single-speaker data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd call it an **interjection**. That may not be quite as specific a word, since an interjection can also be simply exclaiming something, but [to interject](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/interject#English) has the specific definition of interrupting with an aside. Perhaps also **[interpose](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/interpose)** or an **interposition** as a hyponym.

Comment: That’s absolutely standard and common. I’m wondering about conveying a subtle social aspect to it. E.g. a confirmatory interjection or an a clarifying aside

Comment: Ohh nice.  Interpose. That’s a good hyponym.

Comment: I can’t quite think of a hypernym encompassing the aspect I’m interested in, the broader category. It may not be an english question, but a question of some social commentary system